# How to get numbers of online users using .NET Identity 2.0 in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, identity

Do guys know that how to get numbers of online users using .NET identity 2.0 membership providers in MVC 5 ?

I have scan the methods in UserManager that Identity sample gives but no helping.

Comment: ASP.NET Identity does not provide any function to get number of onlines users. You'll have to implement your own logic.

Answer (score 4):

This should be somewhat accurate at displaying the user count. It uses a cache to store the user's IP address and returns a count of individual IPs. If two people are behind the same proxy it will count it as one person.

```
using System.Runtime.Caching;

public int UsersOnlineCount
{
    get
    {
        return MemoryCache.Default.Where(kv => kv.Value.ToString() == "User").Count();
    }
}
```

The best way of making sure everyone gets added to the cache is to define some `BaseController` with this in the constructor...

```
public BaseController() : base() 
{
    CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
    policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20);

    MemoryCache.Default.Add(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress, "User", policy);
}
```